Movie about an Angel on a flight
I am trying to remember the title of an 80s/90s movie about a plane crash and a mystery man who saved the passengers. Someone else takes credit for the act while he stays quiet.
At the end of the movie, while this mystery man referred to as "the angel on flight..." is talking to someone in a zoo about the plane crash, a child falls into one of the animals cage and the mystery man takes of his shoes saying something like "take - hold my shoes"

Hero with Dustin Hoffman from 1992?

A not-so-nice man rescues passengers from a crashed airliner, only to see someone else take credit.




https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_(1992_film)
